# Elasticsearch group by and pick up documents having max time stamp

Tags: java, scala, elasticsearch, group-by

I am using the Elasticsearch 6.5. I am looking to find the documents with some filter condition (working fine) and then I need to take only docs which has the MAX timestamp (field in the doc).

Basically when I search the index using below payload, I get the data as shown below (only important fields shown, data has other fields and stuff)

```
{
  "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": { "myfield.date" : "2019-07-02" }
                },
                {
                    "match": { "myfield.data" : "ABC" }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "regexp": { "myOtherFieldId": "myregex1" }
                            },
                            {
                                "regexp": { "myOtherFieldId": "myregex2" }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I am getting the following docs.

```
date, book, id, timestamp
2019-07-02, ABC, PQR_20190703130000_1234, 2019-07-03 13:01:00
2019-07-02, ABC, PQR_20190703140000_234, 2019-07-03 14:01:00
2019-07-02, ABC, PQR_20190704100000_0199, 2019-07-04 10:01:00
```

There are around 1200 messages or docs in total, with above 3 Ids. 
Out of these, **I just need those docs, whose timestamp is latest**.

I am trying to do some aggregations, but not helping.
What should be done to get the only latest docs?

I tried something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": { "myfield.date" : "2019-07-02" }
                },
                {
                    "match": { "myfield.data" : "ABC" }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "regexp": { "myOtherFieldId": "myregex1" }
                            },
                            {
                                "regexp": { "myOtherFieldId": "myregex2" }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
"aggs": {
    "group_by_id" : {
        "terms": { 
            "field": "field1.Id"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "timeStamp": {
                "max": { 
                    "field": "field1.Id"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "max_timestamp": {
        "max_bucket": {
            "buckets_path": "group_by_id>timeStamp"
        }
    }
},
"size": "10000"
}
```

Here I am still getting all the documents. 
Please note that the mapping shows the field1.Id is a keyword.

```
"Id":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}
```

The data retrieved shows NULL for the MAX values.

```
"aggregations": {
        "group_by_id": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "PQR_20190703130000_1234",
                    "doc_count": 947,
                    "timeStamp": {
                        "value": null
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "PQR_20190703140000_234",
                    "doc_count": 947,
                    "timeStamp": {
                        "value": null
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "PQR_20190704100000_0199",
                    "doc_count": 947,
                    "timeStamp": {
                        "value": null
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "max_timestamp": {
            "value": null,
            "keys": []
        }
    }
```

What is missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be

```
"aggs": {
    "timeStamp": {
        "max": { 
            "field": "field1.timestamp"
        }
    }
}
```

instead of

```
"aggs": {
    "timeStamp": {
        "max": { 
            "field": "field1.Id"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried both, since my id also has timestamp in it, max of that will also work. I tried below too, it gives same results.

`"aggs": {
    "timeStamp": {
        "max": { 
            "field": "field1.timestamp.keyword"
        }
    }
}`

Please note that field is a keyword like id.
`"timeStamp":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}`

So, I have to use .keyword, otherwise it throws error 
`Expected numeric type on field [fields1.timeStamp], but got [keyword]`

I am not sure if it has something to do with type: Keyword, that max is not working.

Comment: sure it won't work - even in docs they pointed out `The min and max aggregation operate on the double representation of the data` - for me it means that you cannot use it with `keyword`, you need to privde numeric mapping or script

Comment: Thanks. Since I am fairly new to Elasticsearch, can you point me to some examples or link how to provide the mapping or script in such cases, mainly to find max on timestamp?